Can’t tell which wire has voltage using non contact voltage tester
I’m testing a light switch. I removed the switch plate. I pulled the switch out of the box a couple of inches.
When I try to test the wires using my non-contact voltage tester, the tester detects voltage and sounds off as soon as I get within a few inches of the switch. The tester indicates voltage even before I get the tester anywhere close to the wires. So, I can’t determine which of the wires actually has voltage in it.
Is this a normal issue?

Yep. Use a proper multimeter.

A non contact tester is more to warn you before touching live/hot wires with your fingers, so keeping fingers away a couple of inches is good.
